# Android: hide keyboard when touch inside a customized Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard

I have a customized Dialog.  Inside the dialog, there's an EditText.  When I touch inside the EditText, the soft keyboard is shown.  I want to hide this keyboard when I touch inside the other place of the Dialog.

I know how to hide a keyboard in activity.  I just don't know how to do this in Dialog.

Thank you.

Comment: have you searched how to hide software keyboard? there are a lot of examples here. look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: @viperbone hi, I have searched how to hide software keyboard in activity, use dispatchTouchEvent.  but I just don't know how to do this in a dialog.

Comment: oh, good. You could write that in your question so it's clear you search a specially a method to hide the keyboard within a dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that easy by using focuslisners, see my code sample below:

```
EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() 
        { 
            @Override 
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
            { 
                if (hasFocus) 
                { 
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    imm.showSoftInput(EditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT); 
                }
                else
                {
                   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            } 
        });
```

edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:focusable = "true"
            android:isFocusableInTouchMode = "true"
            android:clickable = "true" > 

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="hint"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            </LinearLayout>         
    </RelativeLayout>
```

\to be sure to get focus:

```
    LinearLayout actionHide = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        actionHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                actionHide.requestFocus(); // use this to trigger the focus listner
                //or use code below to set the keyboard to hidden
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, this code can't work in the dialog.  I mean, when I touch the outside of the EditText, this EditText is still on focus.  Thank you.  Do you have other ideas?

Comment: You need to set the dialog focusable, then it does work. (See my edit)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.  I know what you mean now.  I set the focusable true for the EditText.  Now I can detect the focus change event: only when I touch the EditText.  When I touch the outside of the EditText, the code can't detect focus changed event.  So I set the focusable of the Dialog's layout.  But this still doesn't work.  I think out an poor way to deal with this: I have an imageview in the dialog.  I set onclicklistener to this imageView to hide the keyboard.  But this is not good.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Vigor I did edit my answer. I did make the wrapper clicable and if someone clicks outside the edittext the keyboard will be set to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting [InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) for Edittext :

```
InputMethodManager input_manager = (InputMethodManager) 
                       getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
input_manager.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Comment: Didn't Vigor asked for hidding the keyboard?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.  But it dosen't work.  I wan't to detect touch event in the Dialog.  Do you have any idea?